# How can Mersenne Prime rule be valid if $2047$ isn't prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The rule of Mersenne Prime says that $2^p - 1$ is prime if $p$ is prime.

$2^{11} - 1 = 2047$ satisfies the condition, but it's not a prime as it can be divided by two prime numbers $23$ and $89$. Then, why do we use Mersenne Prime thing at all?

Last I checked, the biggest known prime today is a Mersenne Prime. Can't it be wrong?

Comment: The true claim is that "if $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime".  It appears that quite a few of the numbers $2^p-1$ are prime, so they provide fertile ground for finding primes.

Comment: @lulu: it is also easier to check whether a number of the form $2^p-1$ is prime than many other potential primes of similar magnitude

Comment: @Henry  An excellent (and quite true) point.

Comment: @Henry Lucas-Lehmer test?

Comment: Who told you that rule? I think you've misunderstood it.

Comment: @Thomas I read it in Rosen's Discrete Mathematics. I misinterpreted what the book wanted to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a Mersenne prime is a number $m$ such that

$$m = 2^n -1$$

is prime. **Then** $n$ is also prime.

Answer (score 1):

$2^p-1$ is prime *implies* $p$ is prime. Not the other way around, that is, not every prime $p$ makes $2^p-1$ a prime.

For now, there's no way to generate an arbitrary large prime, hence the record of largest prime.

The reason we try to find prime of the form $2^p-1$ is partially because of how the computers are designed (working on bits $0$ and $1$).

Comment: Lucas-Lehmer test?

Comment: "For now, there's no way to generate an arbitrary large prime,[...]" I think this is misleading. There are such ways, but to actually carry them out is the challenge there.